# Basis of Trigonometry and sine of an angle and of a number.

Tags: trigonometry

Since equiangular triangles are similar, the ratios of its sides are proportional. So, consider two right triangles $ ABC $ and$ A'B'C'$ with the same angles. Then

$\sin \alpha = \frac{AB}{BC} =  \frac{A'B'}{B'C'}$ because these ratios are proportional, so $\sin \alpha $ depends only of the angle and that's why is a function of it. But my question is, why the proportionality of these ratios implies the existence of a constant $ C $ which is the sine of these angle? We known that the ratios of the sides of similar triangles are equal, but does this indeed means that there exist such numerical constant $C$ -the sine- for every angle? Is this the basis and the fundamental fact by which right triangle trigonometry works?

And also, what are the differences between $\sin 1^\circ $ and $\sin 1$? (That's to say, the sine of one degre and the sine of the number 1)

Comment: Yes, it means so